# CentOS yum install gcc error: glibc-common conflicts with glibc

Tags: centos, gcc, glibc

I met a problem with installing gcc on my CentOS.

Outputs of my command sudo yum install gcc:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * addons: centos.ustc.edu.cn
 * base: centos.ustc.edu.cn
 * extras: mirror.bit.edu.cn
 * updates: centos.ustc.edu.cn
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package gcc.x86_64 0:4.1.2-54.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: cpp = 4.1.2-54.el5 for package: gcc
--> Processing Dependency: libgomp >= 4.1.2-54.el5 for package: gcc
--> Processing Dependency: libgcc >= 4.1.2-54.el5 for package: gcc
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-devel >= 2.2.90-12 for package: gcc
--> Running transaction check
---> Package cpp.x86_64 0:4.1.2-54.el5 set to be updated
---> Package glibc-devel.x86_64 0:2.5-118.el5_10.2 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-headers = 2.5-118.el5_10.2 for package: glibc-devel
--> Processing Dependency: glibc = 2.5-118.el5_10.2 for package: glibc-devel
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-headers for package: glibc-devel
---> Package libgcc.i386 0:4.1.2-54.el5 set to be updated
---> Package libgcc.x86_64 0:4.1.2-54.el5 set to be updated
---> Package libgomp.x86_64 0:4.4.7-1.el5 set to be updated
--> Running transaction check
--> Processing Dependency: glibc = 2.5-49 for package: nscd
---> Package glibc.x86_64 0:2.5-118.el5_10.2 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-common = 2.5-118.el5_10.2 for package: glibc
---> Package glibc-headers.x86_64 0:2.5-118.el5_10.2 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: kernel-headers >= 2.2.1 for package: glibc-headers
--> Processing Dependency: kernel-headers for package: glibc-headers
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glibc-common.x86_64 0:2.5-118.el5_10.2 set to be updated
---> Package kernel-headers.x86_64 0:2.6.18-371.4.1.el5 set to be updated
---> Package nscd.x86_64 0:2.5-118.el5_10.2 set to be updated
--> Processing Conflict: glibc-common conflicts glibc > 2.5
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
glibc-common-2.5-118.el5_10.2.x86_64 from updates has depsolving problems
  --> glibc-common conflicts with glibc
Error: glibc-common conflicts with glibc
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I can not figure out what the "conflict" means, and I found nothing after a Google search. How can I get gcc working?

Answer (score 5):

The conflict is arising as your CentOS is already having a glibc version which is not allowing glibc-common to install itself and related dependencies.

run `rpm -qa | grep glibc` and check for the output.

You may get 2 different versions as suppose :

```
glibc-common-2.12-1.80.el6_3.5.x86_64
glibc-common-2.12-1.80.el6_3.4.x86_64
```

If so then remove the 3.5 version:

```
rpm -e glibc-common-2.12-1.80.el6_3.5.x86_64
```

After that, run `yum update` and `yum install gcc`

Answer (score 3):

As the answer by Shashank Bajpai says, you have a version of a package that needs to be updated, but can't be.

You could try `yum install --skip-broken gcc` to install what can be installed without conflicts, but that might turn out to be nothing. In any case, this sounds like a broken repository, or perhaps you've got an index for an incomplete repository (during updating it?) or something weird like that. Try `yum clean metadata` and run your command again, chances are it will now work.